# Flutter - Web App doesn't start - Assertion failed: "boolean expression must not be null"

Tags: flutter, dart, google-chrome

I created a new flutter project and when trying to run it with

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

I get the following error message in the console.

```
Unhandled error detected in the injected client.js script.

You can disable this script in webdev by passing --no-injected-client if it
is preventing your app from loading, but note that this will also prevent
all debugging and hot reload/restart functionality from working.

The original error is below, please file an issue at
https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/issues/new and attach this output:

Assertion failed: "boolean expression must not be null"
Assertion failed: "boolean expression must not be null"
    at Object.wrapException (http://localhost:62764/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1420:43)
    [...]
    at _AsyncRun__initializeScheduleImmediate_internalCallback.call$1 (http://localhost:62764/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12119:9)
```

I tried running 'flutter clean', deleted the .dart_tool folder, and updated the SDK version to the latest. It's a new project without any own implementations. (Running the Application on the android emulator works just fine.)

I'm using visual studio code.

Comment: I think I had this same error and I had to completely reinstall Flutter. I'm not entirely certain it was the same error, it was a month or two ago and I can't remember if the stack trace of the error was at "Object.wrapException".

Comment: Thanks @Clavum this was actually the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Removing (https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/uninstall?tab=windows) and installing the flutter SDK resolved the error.